# Как регулировать положение элементов NSTabViewController в toolbar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, toolbar

Пишу приложение на *OS X*. Создал основную менюшку с помощью `TabViewController`. Поднял элементы в `Toolbar`. То есть выбрал стиль `Toolbar`. Они оказались как и должны по умолчанию слева. Есть возможность поместить их по середине?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]